# Rename files in a folder using part of text of original name (batch file, powershell, other solution)

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, rename, filenames

I have a folder with more files to rename.

I need to move a part of original name in another position.

al part in filename are separated from " - " (first part - thirth part - second part.gif)

All files use the same structure.

My original files:

```
111111111 - 333333333 - 2222222222.txt
AAAA AAA - CCC CCCC - BBB BBB.mp3
1home - 3home - 2home.jpg
```

Espected result:

```
111111111 - 2222222222 - 333333333.txt
AAAA AAA - BBB BBB - CCC CCCC.mp3
1home - 2home - 3home.jpg
```

All file name are composed 3 part i need to move second part with third part

Extension must not be changed keep original extension.

Any script, software to do this will be appreciated.

I tryed this Powershell code but seems not working

```
Set-Location C:\pathHere\

Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
    $artist,$album,$song = $_.BaseName.Split(" - ")
    Rename-Item $_ -NewName ($artist + " - " + $song + " - "  + $album + $_.Extension)
}
```

Comment: The first and third files appear to have five parts, and the second one eight parts, _using the standard accepted string delimiter (space)_, so none of them have three parts! If your question is really, **Any script, software to do this**, are you aware that under the community reasons for "Why should this question be closed", there's an option, under "Why isn’t this question suited for Stack Overflow?", of "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more"? Have you taken the [tour], and read through all of the pages under [ask]?

Comment: @Compo Separator is always " - " if you see all filename have always 3 parts. FIRST PART - SECONDS PART - THIRD PART

Comment: Okay, if the spaces are not the delimiters and the hyphens were, your expected results would still be wrong, they would then read, `111111111 - 2222222222- 333333333 .txt`, `AAAA AAA - BBB BBB- CCC CCCC .mp3`, and `1home - 2home- 3home .jpg`. Clearly spaces and hyphens cannot be considered as delimiters, so are you telling us that the basename parts are delimited by a sequence of <singlespace><singlehypen><singlespace>? and can you categorically state that there will never be a hyphen in any filenames, which are not part of that three character sequence?

Comment: You don't need to set the location to get the childitems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I don't really like to answer questions where no batch file coding effort has been shown by the OP when using its tag, but here's a possible [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution nonetheless:

```sh
@Echo Off&SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For %%G In ("* - * - *.*")Do (Set "BaseNameBefore=%%~nG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion&For /F "Tokens=1-4 Delims=?" %%I In (
        "!BaseNameBefore: - =?!")Do EndLocal&If "%%L" == "" If Not %%K == "" (
        Ren "%%G" "%%I - %%K - %%J%%~xG"))
```

*As no coding effort was shown, I'll leave you to break down how the code works yourself, without my explanation.*

Comment: This working thanks i accept your solution

Answer (score 1):

Using PowerShell, I would do this:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -File -Filter '*-*-*.*') | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { $parts = ($_.BaseName -split '-').Trim()
                           '{0} - {1} - {2}{3}' -f $parts[0], $parts[2], $parts[1], $_.Extension
                         }
```

`Get-ChildItem` together with switches `-File` and `-Filter` returns an array of FileInfo objects of files that have 3 'blocks' of text separated by hyphens (`'*-*-*.*'`), so we can be sure these names can be split into three parts.

The result of this is then sent through the pipeline to cmdlet `Rename-Item`, which can take a scriptblock in parameter `-NewName`.
Inside that scriptblock simply split the BaseName of each file into its (Trimmed) separate parts and combine these parts in a different order back to become a new filename. (I like using the `-f` Format operator for things like this, because it makes for very readable code).

**before**

```
D:\TEST
    111111111 - 333333333 - 2222222222.txt
    1home - 3home - 2home.jpg
    AAAA AAA - CCC CCCC - BBB BBB.mp3
```

**after**

```
D:\TEST
    111111111 - 2222222222 - 333333333.txt
    1home - 2home - 3home.jpg
    AAAA AAA - BBB BBB - CCC CCCC.mp3
```

<sup>The reason why `(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -File -Filter '*-*-*.*')` should be put in between brackets is that otherwise, the Get-ChildItem cmdlet can pick up already renamed files while iterating the folder, and thus rename these multiple times.

The brackets make sure the collection of files is completed *before* it is sent through the pipeline.</sup>

**Note** As [Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman) commented, If you are certain the split should be done on `Space Hyphen Space`, just change `-split '-'` into `-split ' - '`

Comment: I like that you added the trim incase there were multiple spaces before or after the hyphen but I still think you need to do the split with the string Space Hyphen Space. They did specifically say that is what it should be split on.  The results will be undesirable if the the user has a file name: `1111-AAAA - 22222 22222 - 333333.txt`.

Comment: @Squashman Thanks, I have added a note for this in my answer.

Comment: I tried and do nothing, why every Powershell code do not working in my pc ?

Comment: @cicoria I don't know what to tell you.  This code also works on my computer using the file name examples you provided.

Comment: @cicoria PowerShell code must be run with PowerShell.. It looks like you are trying to run it from the **cmd** console window?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in your folder:

```
for /f "delims=-. tokens=1,2,3,4"   %i in ('dir /b') do echo rename "%i-%j-%k.%l" "%i-%k-%j.%l">> run-renames.bat
```

Then, a script file **run-renames.bat** will be created:

```
 rename "111111111 - 333333333 - 2222222222.txt" "111111111 - 2222222222- 333333333 .txt"
 rename "1home - 3home - 2home.jpg" "1home - 2home- 3home .jpg"
 rename "AAAA AAA - CCC CCCC - BBB BBB.mp3" "AAAA AAA - BBB BBB- CCC CCCC .mp3"
```

Finally run the new script.
Note: delete run-renames.bat after each time you try, in thay way avoids include itself.

Comment: Do you think they want a space after the 3rd part of the file name before the extension?

Comment: I think that space belongs to second segment (now moved to 3rd position). Maybe the user prefers to keep it. Other option, could be  if you can edit and correct the new script using notepad++ or sublime, if you plan run only one time.

Comment: Reread the users question.  They clearly defined what the input file names are and what they want the output file names to be.  They do not want a space before the file extension.

Comment: I tried but do nothing this script this code do nothing "for /f "delims=-. tokens=1,2,3,4"   %i in ('dir /b') do echo rename "%i-%j-%k.%l" "%i-%k-%j.%l">> run-renames.bat" no creation of batch file

Answer (score 0):

I chose to assign the split up file name to an array.  Notice that I am using `-Split`.  I highly advise you to open up a PS session and type: `get-help about_split`.  This will explain all the options you have with splitting output.

```
get-childitem | ForEach-Object { $arr = $_.BaseName -Split(' - ') ; Rename-Item $_ -NewName ($arr[0] + " - " + $arr[2] + " - "  + $arr[1] + $_.Extension) }
```

Here is my output from running the code.

```
PS C:\Powershell\rename\data> dir

    Directory: C:\Powershell\rename\data


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/26/2021   6:07 PM              0 111111111 - 333333333 - 2222222222.txt
-a----        2/26/2021   6:56 PM              0 1home - 3home - 2home.jpg
-a----        2/26/2021   6:56 PM              0 AAAA AAA - CCC CCCC - BBB BBB.mp3


PS C:\Powershell\rename\data> get-childitem | ForEach-Object { $arr = $_.BaseName -Split(' - ') ; Rename-Item $_ -NewName ($arr[0] + " - " + $arr[2] + " - "  + $arr[1] + $_.Extension) }
PS C:\Powershell\rename\data> dir


    Directory: C:\Powershell\rename\data


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/26/2021   6:07 PM              0 111111111 - 2222222222 - 333333333.txt
-a----        2/26/2021   6:56 PM              0 1home - 2home - 3home.jpg
-a----        2/26/2021   6:56 PM              0 AAAA AAA - BBB BBB - CCC CCCC.mp3


PS C:\Powershell\rename\data>
```

Comment: Tryed and do not rename nothing, seems not working.

Comment: @cicoria works on my computer using your file names as input.  I will add some proof to show you.